# Create a table of Quantiles in R for multiple Subsets of Data

Tags: r, indexing

I'm trying to create a table of quantiles in **R** for multiple subsets of data.

Right now, I have a vector of ids (`p_ids`) in table `DATA`, which are not consecutive. For each value in `p_ids`, I am looking to list the quantiles.

So far, I've tried variations of:

```
i <- 1
n <- 1

for (i in p_ids) {
    while(n <= nrow(data)) {
        quantiles[n] <- quantile(subset(alldata$variableA, alldata$variableB == i),
                                 probs = c(0,1,2,3)/3)
        n <- n + 1
    }
}
```

I know my issue lies somewhere in the index, but I can't seem to get where the index should go. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into using aggregate to do your quantiles for you 
http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/aggregate.html

setting FUN=quantiles and by=p_ids should do what you want.

That is unless I've misunderstood your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think the aggregate function will save me a lot of time. I've done further research, but seem to keep getting an error that 'by' must be a list. I've tried to use both a value and data frame. My code is: aggregate(x = mydata$q1, by = p_ids, fun = median) Right now, to generate the "list" of p_ids, I am using the unique function -- p_ids <- unique(mydata$p_id).

Comment: Also realized that if i use list(), I take care of that issue, but then end up with the error message that the arguments must have same length..  (code is: aggregate(x = mydata$q1, by = list(p_ids), fun = median).

Comment: Figured it out, finally. if you're also an R newbie: aggregate(x = mydata, by = list(mydata$v1), fun = median). Under this, mydata must be a data frame where all of the factors are numeric (so a median can be computed) and then mydata$v1 is the vector by which you want the items grouped -- for me that was the field p_id. !

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `cut()`. E.g.:

```
q <- cut(p_ids, 2) 
data.frame(P_id = p_ids, Bin = q)
```

The second argument of `cut()` being how many bins you want.